# SCP file copy gets frozen in mid transfer

Tags: windows, scp, git-bash

For some reason I am experiencing an issue with scp/network that file download gets stuck in mid transfer. Usually at the end of the completion, like 90%, 97% or 99%. Files are around 200mb to 1,5gb.

For example for the first 10 files the transfer could have completed fine, but then for random file this happens:

```
99% 1347MB  20.0MB/s   00:00 ETA
```

I waited for half an hour, but nothing...

Is it due to the fact that I am using Windows 10 and running git-bash in it? Is there any other command line tool I could use for the scp in Windows 10 environment?

How it would be possible to debug what is causing this issue, is there any verbose option in `scp` command?

Answer (score 0):

It can be caused by a damaged sector/cluster in the disk
If you are using Windows 
Start>cmd.exe —-> Run it as administrator
write:
chkdsk /f 
Then press Y and reboot system
If there’s damaged sectors/clusters in the disk, will be repaired

Comment: It will *not* be repaired. The damaged sectors will be marked as damaged to keep the os from trying to use them again... But damaged sectors often indicate a more serious problem

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but does not seem to be the case in this situation.